# "Interpretive search" with Python and Postgres

Tags: django, algorithm, postgresql, search, solr

I've been working on building a Django-powered website that acts almost like Google images but for a specific type of image format (.FITS for those who are interested). Basically, it stores the image, along with a large amount of metadata about the image, in a Postgres backend. The data (set by a django model) is structured as a file field, a set of n required key-value pairs, and a dictionary of unknown key-value pairs.

Now that the UI and gallery components are done, I'm on to building the search function for the database, and I'm a bit stuck.

It needs to be able to handle queries like "images from 1997 to 2005 of [this object]" or "images uploaded by this user" i.e. to relate a "casual" query to a specific query it should make on the database.

My main question is: **for most services that have a feature like this, is there some sort of defined way of doing this?** I've heard about Solr/Elasticsearch etc, and I'm working through the docs on those, I just want to know if I'm heading in the right direction before I finish that or start hacking a chain of django filters.

Thanks!